# When using imagepng it shows symbols and random characters but no image

Tags: php, image, oop, gd

I am trying to resize images if they are too big in my image section. I've wrote code and I've got it all right, except when I use imagepng it will just show random characters and symbols. I do not completely understand why it is causing the issue. I remember having this issue in the past and never got it fixed.

ResizeImage Class:

```
        class ResizeImage{
        private $image;
        private $imageResized;
        private $width;
        private $height;
        private $imageSupport;
        private $imageType;

        public function __construct($image){
            $this->imageSupport = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif");
            $this->image = $this->openImage($image);
            $this->width = imagesx($this->image);
            $this->height = imagesy($this->image);
        }

        private function openImage($file){
            $fileTypeSize = explode(".", $file);
            $this->imageType = $fileTypeSize[count($fileTypeSize) - 1];
            switch($this->imageType){
                case 'jpg':
                case 'jpeg':
                    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                    break;
                case 'gif':
                    $image = imagecreatefromgif($file);
                    break;
                case 'png':
                    $image = imagecreatefrompng($file);
                    break;
                default:
                    $image = false;
                    break;
            }
            return $image;
        }

        public function resizeImage($newWidth, $newHeight, $option="auto"){
            //Get optimal size based on $option
            $optionArray = $this->getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, strtolower($option));

            $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
            $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];

            $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight);
            imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $this->width, $this->height);

            if($option == 'crop'){
                $this->crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight);
            }
        }

        private function getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option){
           switch ($option)  
            {  
                case 'exact':  
                    $optimalWidth = $newWidth;  
                    $optimalHeight = $newHeight;  
                    break;  
                case 'portrait':  
                    $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);  
                    $optimalHeight = $newHeight;  
                    break;  
                case 'landscape':  
                    $optimalWidth = $newWidth;  
                    $optimalHeight = $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);  
                    break;  
                case 'auto':  
                    $optionArray = $this->getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight);  
                    $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];  
                    $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];  
                    break;  
                case 'crop':  
                    $optionArray = $this->getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight);  
                    $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];  
                    $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];  
                    break;  
            }  
            return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);  
        } 

        private function getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight)  
        {  
            $ratio = $this->width / $this->height;  
            $newWidth = $newHeight * $ratio;  
            return $newWidth;  
        }  

        private function getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth)  
        {  
            $ratio = $this->height / $this->width;  
            $newHeight = $newWidth * $ratio;  
            return $newHeight;  
        }  

        private function getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight)  
        {  
            if ($this->height < $this->width)  
            // *** Image to be resized is wider (landscape)  
            {  
                $optimalWidth = $newWidth;  
                $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);  
            }  
            elseif ($this->height > $this->width)  
            // *** Image to be resized is taller (portrait)  
            {  
                $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);  
                $optimalHeight= $newHeight;  
            }  
            else  
            // *** Image to be resizerd is a square  
            {  
                if ($newHeight < $newWidth) {  
                    $optimalWidth = $newWidth;  
                    $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);  
                } else if ($newHeight > $newWidth) {  
                    $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);  
                    $optimalHeight= $newHeight;  
                } else {  
                    // *** Sqaure being resized to a square  
                    $optimalWidth = $newWidth;  
                    $optimalHeight= $newHeight;  
                }  
            }  

            return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);  
        }  

        private function getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight){
            $heightRatio = $this->height / $newHeight;  
            $widthRatio  = $this->width /  $newWidth;  

            if ($heightRatio < $widthRatio) {  
                $optimalRatio = $heightRatio;  
            } else {  
                $optimalRatio = $widthRatio;  
            }  

            $optimalHeight = $this->height / $optimalRatio;  
            $optimalWidth  = $this->width  / $optimalRatio;  

            return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);  
        }  

        private function crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight)  
        {  
            // *** Find center - this will be used for the crop  
            $cropStartX = ( $optimalWidth / 2) - ( $newWidth /2 );  
            $cropStartY = ( $optimalHeight/ 2) - ( $newHeight/2 );  

            $crop = $this->imageResized;  
            //imagedestroy($this->imageResized);  

            // *** Now crop from center to exact requested size  
            $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth , $newHeight);  
            imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $crop , 0, 0, $cropStartX, $cropStartY, $newWidth, $newHeight , $newWidth, $newHeight);  
        }  

        public function saveImage($savePath, $imageQuality="100"){
            $fileType = $this->imageType;
            switch($fileType)  
            {  
                case '.jpg':  
                case '.jpeg':  
                    if (imagetypes() & IMG_JPG) {  
                        imagejpeg($this->imageResized, $savePath, $imageQuality);  
                    }  
                    break;  

                case '.gif':  
                    if (imagetypes() & IMG_GIF) {  
                        imagegif($this->imageResized, $savePath);  
                    }  
                    break;  

                case '.png':  
                    // *** Scale quality from 0-100 to 0-9  
                    $scaleQuality = round(($imageQuality/100) * 9);  

                    // *** Invert quality setting as 0 is best, not 9  
                    $invertScaleQuality = 9 - $scaleQuality;  

                    if (imagetypes() & IMG_PNG) {  
                        imagepng($this->imageResized, $savePath, $invertScaleQuality);  
                    }  
                    break;  

                // ... etc  

                default:  
                    // *** No extension - No save.  
                    break;  
            }  

            imagedestroy($this->imageResized);  
        }  

        public function loadImage(){
            $image;
            switch($this->imageType){
                case 'jpeg':
                case 'jpg':
                    $image = imagejpeg($this->imageResized);
                    break;
                case 'png':
                    $image = imagepng($this->imageResized);
                    break;
                case 'gif':
                    $image = imagegif($this->imageResized);
                    break;
                default:
                    $image = false;
            }

            return $image;
        }
    }
```

I am calling loadImage() within my code. Now the output I am getting is.

```
    ‰PNG  IHDR–ps~* IDATxœí}ypÇyï×=ÇÞXìâ¾II¼‰4)ò‰:-+:[–”<Ù)Ee=;©g§Ê±c;ò{%_e»R±¥ø%O±ägË§$G’Y’©H"­ƒ¤xAI‰Å]ì½;WïÙ=È"ªÐ5µ˜éùMwOýõïûº{‘¦PS&,pá³`~¼Lj‹\ ©Ç#"5¢ qzŒ!ãòá=€çÞ³ü.sÖ—\FÒF<-zÛxòeƒˆf!ž_\ê·hj"Š5¬+lQ\0`a¡™c,-¢°\\¦õýR€K•|q‚KÅä%²Ä…‹¼Ä…—/ë%.\âÂ%.¼Bèm‰ç'½Í¼Ä…—/ë%.\âÂ%.¼Bèm‰ç'½Í¼Ä…—/ë…âBR¦ÒÍÏ2‡ dŽàR¿¥R˜…ÓçgggSƒXio­s¯«´·‹¦lÜK™/3¸¨8K¾ŒØ cÁ—e/ žUBÞúƒ/ ü«¤Æ A@xÎ¾¹ñþ55·éÕ\¶¹¤¼ààR1@.DÄsÁß¿qþ{ˆ€A@i°¡æþ-Ëî.¬ÁÂD`‰Š“JðHàß˜.?@zAPŽ~b|f hït™Ë9_ð\¸ðâŽ„ßL)@=SÐ3ÎDôýFUU£HEÓ,l….Õyš¿0’A$Æ#-Dmthìäììl™’MyÁÁ¥bÌ‰ðæX³i`yr.ü'‚õ2 0U““JPÖ’€(pv‡P%p´0Aa2$T§vù1Þ7Fü~?Çq¥ P¾r%úRÃTDDÞ[4é9šïl)¨¬Å/„ßê¾Lô),ÉPB8ŽÚ|ö¶öªkÛý{‚¯hún±‰þö"BÒIuvŒDÂÆÏ[ðy•ó2ƒçÂ…åÞÇ¬—†ýùíÅr~QpÑ_6zõèèÑô˜‘9d’Ò4-1•8=ï=øé†¦O¬©ý3³[²®wmÒ$;'ÊÀP7Fum¤dàdŒE;DQ,UCt²¼h™/¸Œkž–z}è{ÿ5ðHzLW$$€ÑêôÒ,òvà_ÿãØ¢‰iú\Muì†T\£ É¤À‹d*9æj®_Q__oô¢$.¤–ØËÉ… ©±—ú¾Ú7ý¢©YS2ã€¹Q!Bœï}êèßÎDæVI)·©ý6epÓX¿ŒõÆ‰ž=yû)¬uvoÙ²µ¡¡¡|«Z´\!O›‹",IÌ½—ŸXcê«ƒßî¾’y"kˆ¦jˆ€¥`“–ß±é».‡×hÚ²,Ÿ>‹Åxž¯­­­¯¯w8fI}AËë—ºu™Á¥‚YÆ6Fzbü©7ÏÿŸl)JK,/Þ¸  )ho¹ïÆoXüÝœcŒ€n¿”±ë,.BðEufaÆHXð5ÌJ1cÅ`±Ã4l–#'áC£cç-™B(¥<ÏuçÞÎ¸Œ¤s¦\ùç!_6z·æÖãÒÌLb€dD€u§Îz0Ô‘&°>CírïàaMÓ,éù6¬BØb[·¨tÆ/%‡MÊƒä;9!eü0K”˜ÎlN~hôt2™,ßÖà•.cNdaüÂ„b,Û7Z£«R=A¤3¡‰x<^ªåëkñƒ/-‰àB‘jLÕ†PÞð„ˆ±y!Éd2•J]4GK9¯ðâåBŽØš¸­¬¶!˜4òâe…)SÅÈkî$TJ½Ô|Áó*Fyð\¸paÖÎ¸ÄUE^„rö+f5/siUVŒ)¥ cÉMž™¤ÆÂÉ‘hz4©Î0”9bwru[ƒ×Ñd·¹_DV“3‰sãÑwRJˆ§Îgw{½Ó^QØ÷Ì½s—Š1WìÂÌú-<ºÒ9ÙdDfˆÊèî‹ù…ˆ@( OI~¾ZŸ‚(Z€¢ .%ÏöN=Ûz1©N› E¤±Õ~ãê†ë+½Uæ¡8Æ´ÓSÏû±Ê¤lÜÓu¶«w´þmeEÇñ—š‹>bèîÂø….»¯’v2 éîæü ýÒ8!²ü» K,E£Ãá˜K¦zñÂ©‘ÿzøÄä“qe:?;–`ÓÉÇ=215¢è55zíÑWXÖ„@À éÍ7/|jfLÓ´R–àE«k.^¤\H ]S»/•Ò,NBés‚˜ÂÓ’:ãojlr¹\–ô‹ò "FÓc¯}s,~‚fÄ°Iíàþelb„1†ˆ*“NNüŠ@ÀŽ€ éPïÀ¡D"Qø‚—“l¾p}û^.ÞÀ˜© Ìç˜WÁ/‚¦âðÉD­sUkk«>zQ^Q™t8ðøT²Ï¢å†®#f=HÞ9<ðëÙð,(Z"”B H H‚„ aç'{"‘Hù:±Ü*ß©–¹µ¸üB°Ûì»Úþ*<Î€äk^NpKè%íÇúª×¬ZÛÒÒbH+Å+ˆ8;=>XÒËDÂÐðDq’8sî„,Ë’¤™úOë‰„‰Da»¿œ~á‚­#¥”®]±m9cxZ&”ähÉÌ…ÅÎ GB“éþ×`EÓ†Í›7WUUÍÉEe t@e*CÂ€èË?ôôI $†¦„#aï¬[Œ"šÆˆ’p†ÏÌ…†«ÄIZ"œ›IOÆû'cç¦C³©Ñ”e¨™=*½dn·ûÚMw¹f¶ÌÒ”£$w É»Ì”£3Ô‰çÓµB÷Î;Vv¶Šª&©š¬1•!³ømFá5M™Nô!Ú¢DÔá`0( ¶ÎÊÐÂñ‡xÀW_¹ÒårYªÈòÅÚ÷bñ€1MÒ’ƒ¡·G"'¦q9”CˆºÍ€ê|nÑWãZÑ\Ñ½¢êj;ï¡„JiccÓ‡¯úÔ³¯pCÓo4¯ur|ìøøï†ÃÇ4Ì¼±¶UÌJ#S7á[*Öoh¸y™«w€,Ë}}}¯¼þâÉÀœË"Õ­vÁ®O°gê–i(KlúBrøp*8¬ØÜjK·¸bc¥¯ÖFùìÒ(@d¨*È4´“ê•U{7¶|¤ª¢‘çýåSrä×ï~.,](Ue…!u¾öê†vìØ)B$>Õÿö@ð`$5.%"u­U7mÜÜÜÜl³Ùô¾´|uAæ.…Dc¢ø¢ìU˜„¢¥OMí{ä©P*`jµ˜ù¤HzH¼¶úí-í®ßgãÜŠ¢£Gß9zòÐ…P/ºÃœC¦ &£§‰I.6-ÉtÖßÄ-ëö6u¸]^’i2$—6 †RZã5ï†ú;¶,»Õ[á'„¤åÄóg‹ŸÈ´§L%!b&Ì9Óâ$Î4ïí¼Û¶í¢("b*• …B¡Ù ,)n·»ªªª²²’ç‹øõEëæÃPLeKç½væBøä+CÿwËÜS5­ŽÚV§·Ú&Ø¨þŽŒ¡ª0MEdH)áxÂ ”RšÊRq­NÜxÃÚÏ6Ö,GÀ7†|tê—s©D½à©#ëoýo÷uuué}²…e­˜œZ,Úµ3ÕWtdô75ýQ€ìw|ÆàÌ,¥ÎÈ2#M’—xNI PàÖ×Þ´·í¯v'c,™L†B¡p8œL&c)5òÖ…Ÿ†µ_t¸yN¤™&ÂÊäùDx*N¨ˆèàœ^Þ[c÷×ÛnAoR©¸jK7Þºî‹í-]£ÁsÏ}IfIsÅXú#$'ÄšàÍùðíæ~²°~ÊÜúÓÁ¥‚YÆsåÂHzú7§¾ˆžÐ#Íïž{ £šh–qOsÕ«Ò!T‹+îìþRmE[¦¹0€²–úmï·gßäø<ƒPSÙh_ì|o”)è©=~Ñá(ŠÌä”ªš¾:;¡Rq…7|lë?6Öµ½Ö÷Ä©Ø³ùÂ*˜ á·V\Õ]Û·ow:¥¨à=ÒÛ¼ÀïÎ¦ÆÑóÁäùòHsJ!HFg2:È Ãœmc!à"uíúJkÍj=†1íàÐOÞ¸ðSš]­ÿ ÆO„‡{ÂÞj[ý OeMtpO !Œ¡*kÉ˜Ÿ•+ªlÞZ»þî‰°â“×b÷?ÕþpîÑqí h.‚Ù F ‚ïTwUßpýu7444”Zzúžém^à÷ œžüÉñ¿ŸMÍBï;ó¡yn¥DSYd*žJKqUS¡D´sž*›¯Ñasò¨™]¤¬tØ˜ÿ®îÿÕZ³ FÂ§~~üï‘6ÕÿŒõÇÎ¼1]ÕälíòzªD‹‚"È)5’^ÁåôÏcfÇ¤íUyÓÎ{‚áÉ×~:o!U_Y‰sÑwk;|»®Ù½gùòå‚ \"z»|\—g?úw¡T€,Òb Éý„€*³Ñ³Ñ#Áè´¤iú€"J(%œ@í.¾¡ÓÓ¶¾Òå39›zYBÀ¦UßÝýp}UÓ¯O~m(|˜rúÈd&ÏTLéyu’¬ÜRå­±QÎPË[€”TÓ Õíy‘Uf±ó¶ûv~kUÇšé™©£g_ˆ¿žÆÀ–&”1…(QAžª°GÚ»VnÞ´qSss³ ¥*ÝRW‹—Múéñ/ŸŸÈÔ_¦º³D‡³6uõ#$zöON Çç­µWÔØ^9Ê¦¡*iÉˆŸ•‘aû&ËZ/åL_fRD/¶ïYq÷o¾TƒZ Âø¹èàÑÐ²u¾ºnAä t`Ó (qx½ø¡±äZñŽ^wEEE"‘½ž˜Å£LE—Ó]S]×ÚÒÖÔÔäõz +ôRÐÛ¼ÀïñåþÇ^øyNJ¥—¸p¡göØïÇ™Êª[]u+=þF§£BàEª3""0 U™¥¢òìX*Húêí+·U 6ÎRMe˜°{Jpp`"ND<÷öL<(w\UåñÛò^Ìl`eS“Óš¦1»[W&SZj°ò¯¯ÿzÇÊNJ©¦i²,§Óiýnžçm6›ÍfÓ…wQÞZ<\XüûBD¼9ýÆÈÓ:ñ@ù"\x7|ôw£¢ƒoÞäo\Uá©¶ñ"gùÞ–@°svà®¶W6:'ú£ƒÇfWl©¢|ž7Iy*I9¦¹yJ8b$€J ÍáD'„äoCh@€ò”!‚@Åñ¡@_kK›Ãáàyžã¸¢ÓÅsa,ÃS¼¤à2ŠkŠÏj¨þgß¿ªLÖ'É”<™OõìŸ°»…WU/ßì÷68ucÎtoã*müHÉx(1&ä á<’L¨™9 DCÂDO9j™‡ÊNîƒ1í‡HÊ0 )¡?mLÒÒ"Ù¦æ_(ÑRÂ¾tàR1æDŠÌ"bÏÄë#‘Ó˜7SdšT¯2Uf§^›D€¶MUk*í"£Þ‹Ìè‘@‰Ã+6tzS 56#ÆÌb&‚ƒKÅUYf cúl%€£RT¦ªXªI™MË—+Nä"‰Ù´”.¬”¢aŽìuéÀe¸Ðˆ/Ò‘OL'.fÅ8 wŽY±cpáä¬»ÊV×Qa¯€@~Çe;a@Bœ•"'R)©B~Û‡GHFUIb ‘qUÙƒT<ÛÁ³ÁÆ¹•!Ð0w%’")²‚ïë¬Þ¥—ê<Í€"CoŽ<€y“¬‡^ûbA)’«ZÝî;¡Ôè{MÚ–SDfUD‚Hˆ«Ê–Š«ŒäÍÇ2ÑÅ3†©¸jÐ›½Btøl± ¤(¨O¯#è&²“ïj$CÆp.ÔUE¦ïšŒpÅsaBŽ„Nd;Ÿ‹p!žJó"õ6:;o_ÆŠëEÉvÒœSUDfMìn!’•1 à¨·ÑÉb!I_üÇ¬ƒèòS4`œ.Wd,C´RJå‰Í²iÂŠ±/x4­& >IÁâdF SlÁáµéÓh^ ÌÓKB'R¦ç’×^!HIMJjú¥Æ€wð .Yb±$ËšÆòxQc¨j¨¨˜UPSûcˆ¨n›Ï¼t¸|¸"¸0Ï/T˜|vúÔG @f")7&šõÜ2usÔæx‡æ;^v6ÛR·áižë™ó ¥$U—ywŽÊ %Uy 6J9 P·zG3£~y˜Éu5Í†/¸ ®Þ¼ÀsñóD˜”##‘³@rÕ[â$—åoçOÐ>1·8ž2†„fg ²2&„Øœ\",»j”Ëíš@EÎ&PMaŒ¡¬hLŸZ"Ñ‡UÑÒ˜IS£´­{…Ûížc˜—Š1÷®yßTDÒ¡™ÄDf#HsÆâ9ÁÉ«šæ±’œ •Œ)¼J@fÿ-fºM€·QiFÖT”ËÇ„òœŽÌ%ÉŒ¢˜[ÈDªŠ¶´µ,7ïž`®šEË…E1ìØ¼E´¡ä”¬I”+X¡PG…Œ*Œ+x 0‰’—™Õ+…· áDN•4EF"˜ b.‘ÑÚÍËý"š¤‡^¾£±±QŸ‚˜K¸"¸0Ï©´CfrŠ{óˆ™x¡ÓoBT…•sá/z%EóÂMaŠ¤å;yæRÖÚ“A”‰Ö?çÇàpÜ§4oîÞæóùÌMØø5*åŠóó¸PcjÎ*ÈëÎò[€@»G°{%­Ù2ËUÞc új´‚ÞX/¦¦¡,ivD4ç‘Ó6ƒ#Íº˜]ßŸNÏö§ïÚrËÊ•v»½¼\Ù\¨ÛA¬ó ŒAeƒ36+;üH©ÉÉõe¹ò»9SáëbÌN'3 4Š~õôŒ©ˆ2q*ruóõ;·ïÒ÷€Êá>x\@L-=WÛÅÖf2‡Ï–J¨JZ|Ö Ñ B½Õr$ÑÏ³@ Æ&^–’0JZe"f÷M/RŽbm0”Æ{f»œÛnÙsûòìBŠ¢/R4,8xÞ\H€3¾ÃB!GÖ*j©ˆ¬i`|b¢£Ì#™ºËæÁD¤Ùý*ÍÄ‹FLeRLM†$MCÓ8‘Ù£7> ÍEj*› $ï×¹¯¾ë†¿\»vm©Ï?P\(P²Ìv>yÄ”¿Þ)_M€p"õT;aÉá³e|;0™Ž38Ñô$Ñ‹˜Ý>² ¯3YfCXM…îºmqÎŽÄœUvÑ)óÀÆ[ë?>U1“gÏÇäQ¼~Õ7ï¹µ£££¢¢Bw„«Æ®l.¬´WQªùÔo—È*k×ð"uûmÉ˜"º³Zayå $cˆÏ++{5+k:oýðm‡G^ÿ}ÏsÛ½¢àÇe‚&krR•ãj|2™žR:}Ý·Ü|ÇÆõ›šššJ™0@.ôˆ~7õÇØTÞÚIÓòlk0–ú""¥ÄY!¨ "…ðL hþ²ïR1P¢àõT6Ô5|rÍƒ×oøÈï=÷öðÁÐÌ”d—'Ï "j2“¢²Q…´½Óµášë¯ë^½®¹¹Ùãñ˜÷S‡² ¿0,8x.\˜×‘ºm Îöpb’ˆ¤P‡ ~ëM}0•çuæC,0Rôîý„…,Zx=¦1¼Í•v»]Å¶¦åá»ÿÚ‰›ûÏŸš˜K¦’ªª n»§¶¹®©®¹­yYkK«ÏçÓ¿Y)Ú¨ßß‘ÌK¶tž…—V.tˆÎÕÕß¾ÁYû6K-¸ f[‘B2³½÷Òx ¢a u=ô¹cŠÌÄd…ßï·ÙlzÚn—»½mEc]ÓUÒY–UUeŒB(¥‚ Ø²Aÿ¾-“ïb¢·KË…”ÒÍí;~ÝûohG‹ÍÞ\a¶ygøÖ…°¬ê«Ò²&‘Ù/0Ù<± ©Vh¨­©5/Ìçy·Û}Ñ—_„ôö¾sažŸK©®¨mu­bÌ2´–gsäßÊUxÖé(b @þ³Y4g¸˜-4Å¤.@}uCmmm!¥• %rÎ«¯9†Ïß/$„Rº·ó–tBE‹¨ò\ÁÂ±SC~¤4Øò)‘T¶ÑH„e1\ÙÖ²Ìçó¯d9aŒišfìß³x\=}{?1åR=ŠPd)ð–e;~v¸Ýq“kaq ¹‹˜ºÉRà"ŒW¬WÎ€)GBç’ËÝkÚÛÛu¯<ï6!011qàÀH$"Š¢ËåZ¹råúõë‹¤uyé %-=:»ºzG¬ÿ_è}çÂ"ëHçMKE ±Ì†VÍ\ìÒâ!‰Œx:–¯jmm5Æ,/öæ›o>ýôÓ¡Phzzº§§çë_ÿúÁƒuë¦ðUË3Ê\Àæxã‘D"‡-*rfúÝ_ŸúIRI”IYeêd|Ü0G‹C¿DÄ©ø„¢)…‰X¹0#UJ÷®½Ñ#×2MO1¯»ë/Ð‡Wr\XÎÇøk|ßW\·™†ÁS©Û²®®®êêj(qùòåŸýìg?ÿùÏéK_ºçž{¾ÿýï÷õõ•ÂC¾lc½½½Ð·†..c¯¼òÊË/¿l3Ô^xe tæää;eŠ—¢?>ö/q9†ˆ)%ñòÀóS‰‰Â$„0ÔþãôÏÏ‡Š6…"‹ !Þ ïíkÿ21%g-ÈÜŠD,ñ›Å¢`4OòAÙ‘XÄ¼¢ãi~´²kÕÚÎÎN›Ífi§æÆ˜®v¢(Þxã/¾øbQ^ADUUÍyË²|ðàÁ—_~9šÁš¦éÛèY”COÁÂR½½½ƒƒƒfØx|ìôôÉUÕÝû§2ÕR£üj}Á^•)0™ÿå»OŒD†-àÌ9@_ðÔl*h‘.åB]ì”Òk¯y«ïõ¾è»GÈ×lj¸¥­Ì#™:¶>Oä”>ª­ñwlÙ²¥®®®¨*íè8Ž«©©‰Åbú&³”Ò`0èóùDQœššzã7fff ³³sçÎú§L·Ýv[4­¬¬Ô :¹º\®îîîõë×ëãŒ±£GöôôÈ²\SS³aÃ†öövÆØÌÌÇqápxzzÚçóéþ‰ñÃ±âÞõýðk_D‡—û:ôÄ“JÂÆÛr8ÊÏ$§(áB©;ïhp7nÇW;«»tÌ¦ƒÁät«·ÝÆÛ$5J5dQ9IÏzí¹)k=p_ûÚ×ÌÂ3z|AÚ*W¼qì êH®ØÇÊEÍ”òÁÄÇ@Œ¡ó¼çâø›ÑÚØ²=»÷îØ±£¢¢².D¡äÎœ9öìÙ#Š"(Š²ÿ~¿ß/ŠâáÃ‡Ÿ}öÙ“'OnÜ¸qttô¡‡r¹\³³³Ï=÷ÜèèèæÍ›9Ž;räHooïºuë!§Nzè¡‡fgg=Ïèèè/~ñ—ËÕÞÞNùÝï~÷è£Š¢ÈóüÑ£GûÛß¶´´x½ÞÿøÇï¾ûîÖ­[ÝnwJIþìä¿ïhÙ»¾~KïôI ÙêênP™úÄ±GÇb_½ûD…­r&9ùÿŽÿ0"Ížš:ÑVÙî+^8÷L“§ÕcóŽD†þéÍ‡_8÷›ÉøØÚÚõc±ÀÞúÆTrr tFCÖYÝÅQÎ¨ ,³77¥´¹±å“Wö‘×¿áhGÊÃÇ|4O£Š]1AÌ[Úˆ,<uŒÕlÜ²yûöí~¿Ž~cL–åcÇŽõöö>üðÃÇüñÇ;::|ðAY–¿óïttt<ðÀ~¿_UÕ¾¾¾oûÛÏ<óÌ]wÝ5<<<88¨iÚøøø÷¾÷½Ý»wßsÏ=çøñãýýý>ŸRúÇ?þñ‰'žøô§?½{÷n›Í‹Å^xá…M›6ÝqÇ±X,Nßÿýú6PÃ³ýS‰‰UÕkqCý–cã‡®_ñ·èÑP÷¿x}_û-ëë· ²wò±wþù/6<Ðæm—4éÐèwµ]WÇŸ=óK·èþï»þ÷3½?JÑOó'7æßŽüÓõ+nÝÚ¸Ã0qš)÷ÿAØÔµåžÙOÿää£î<á²ËÔ0o[NCP–îÖ0W²Ã4YPVù0¿- Àô»QÚëí^µþšk®ikk+Ü-Ä°È3<ÏX<ÿÃþ@éëë;xðàwÞ¹bÅŠ£GÖÖÖ~á_hnn~ì±ÇEyàªªª€çù®®®@ŽÑ¿IDATüã=öØÞ½{u¢€W_}ÕívßÿýÇõôôüð‡?üÔ§>õ¡}H’¤ýû÷_{íµûöí£”"bEEÅÇ>ö1I’Ahmm­««…BíííÀ˜v6xJÒÒ¼ý-%5“#ã±@guÂn_û-w­û”È‰ˆØQµ†§|»¯ÃcóÊÉ)†ŒPB4¦ÊšìÝŸßùvÞÉQnuu·@Åzwc»Ñl‹êÓEö`s¹\×lß›L&~uúGžN(U+ËØZÑ[P0š='áÔ‰öxº—wï»v_WW—Q¹Eƒ~KUÕ‰‰‰W_}U—ÍßüÍßìÝ»W|}}½ßï€`0ØÝÝír¹ÌãÈ«W¯ý_`Œ555ñ<âÄ‰G}ôŸø„žT"‘Ð%d.¥ÔápèŽ¾ó¬—cÏïßÝºoUM7ÂSþ7§vzúä 'RBÖ×o¨­*¤„ËYæÈ€î¾MÿãGGùÆëÿð‰uuMÛ¾L¥fø/Sƒ%ÇH¨(¥•••×ï¾‰ ýå±Çm+U{¥h]ph EmëÝlç ”ÈImòpÄvÞß½bÝM7Ý¤“Š¥$E¹Ðf³­Zµê+_ùŠùc]D”$ÉPV›Í6::jišú¾DúÿÒ4ât:'&&z{{yä‘{î¹G—"òÖ}Ÿ×ž±bRäÙ³¿Ü³üïT™Š˜ï¡Cžq«ÿñÚ*ÿçŽ¯8¿ÿç=¹×Ö¦@ Õ0Wï¤Ô©¥¶Z«ªªºîš>uÕgù³¾Ù¡8c™i†÷rd\‚QËèXrì¥¨w´ik÷ö[n¹eëÖ­Ç\˜2º¨[ž…^,ËÆ˜êž={Î;÷öÛo°T*õÂ/´µµÕÖÖêA)Ý½{wOOÏw¿ûÝ{ï½wÏž=”Òd2yîÜ9»Ý¾yóæ—^ziddD3ÆÂáp.?ÐPÝ?øŸ]5ë=¶ ãÎÕ-×T8;sŠ9QCÕüR˜'JI(ñW‡_b¨]³lßr_GèÃÌ.áEÛ4ÌñùêR¼f×oEåž?ùÎ!W;ç¨²QJ³ÛVÎ% dg G1‘gÏ$XŸ½ÅÝ¹eç–]»v­^½ZßÞ³ÿŠr!¥Tï ½–AÐã !ëÖ­»ûî»ðƒŒŽŽÖ××SJ_zé¥@ ðå/Ùn·ëòCÄÕ«Wß~ûíÏ>û¬$I===étúÅ_ŒÇã_ýêWo¾ùæÞÞÞo~ó›þçîñx¦§§Ÿyæ™mÛ¶­\¹RÏW¯å`ræôôÉ¿½úäJëÜkjÖ¿ÔÿÜÆúmáM6J«k`v½+hLcŒiL{¦÷IDyÛ`¨oWë>JË@ŠKg®û‘B*++·mÝVå¯zëÐê×Þ}yB<ï^ns×:)OL#º%e§·B "$‚éð@Bä|jÃ²¶åÛ·o¿êª«ššštßJt›æ ßjoo×§ -àµk×666ê>swçw:Î§žzJÓ4žç×­[÷àƒ¶´´èdF)¥”rw÷Ýws÷ôÓO' AÚÚÚ>ó™Ïx<øÜç>÷ä“O>ùä“©TÊëõîØ±ãÞ{ïÕÅõÕWëÛs+LÞÝv]GÕs9)¡7wÜþÊà„ÐÍW×»¶óŽëVÜbç`çí7®¼Íï¬öØ<íº÷™Ó?£„Þ°òÏ¶5í$@ °mMjp7æCÞ0y¼£¨ð,u§ªj0ŸÏçó¹Ýnc3dKÑZªs[0¥n-fp©`–ñ¼¹°TŠˆ¨(Š¾É<®ºw¥¯y¹¨©R˜ø{îf›s™Ô'¸òOâÂ÷|Â"¤·yç¢Žó?› ‹¦ö'‚¡Àb¼âÀÅS0ö?› CaÑ/¸TÉ'¸TL^"ï.pá³°øèm^à‹rá‚ýÏ¦¹ÀÞx³¾à2’6â—¸pQƒ—¸°¸TÉ'¸TÌ.qa±°Ä…K\¸Ä…K\x…ÐÛÎ/,Nz›x‰/_ÖK\¸Ä…K\x…ÐÛûÎ…ÿˆC³Öü($IEND®B`‚
```

Any ideas? Thank you for your time. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send the `Content-Type` header to the browser for it to render it as an image. Try adding the following before you output anything:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

You can also see it's usage in the example-code in the [`imagepng` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) for a better reference.

Comment: The whole page just says there is an error on it, so I guess the best thing would just be to save the image and then just call it back inside an <img> tag.

Comment: An error? The output you showed above, the text that begins with `PNG  IHDR...`, that is the output that you would see if you opened the "saved image" with a text-editor. Adding the `Content-Type` header will tell your browser to render it as an actual image (and not show the text). Did you add the header and *now* you're receiving an error? If so, what error?

Comment: It says the page that I'm on has errors. It doesn't go into specifics